# React native - build aplication

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, build

I downloaded the react app via npx react-native init AwesomeProject. The application ran for the first time. After stopping through the terminal, the build application pauses and thus see the screen is a few minutes and does not continue.
For Android everything is OK. This "mistake" is just for ios.

Anyone have any idea?
Thank you

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehc9f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. yarn install
3. cd ios
4. pod install
5. cd ..
6. react-native start in your terminal
7. open the Xcode and click the Product/Run button manually.
8. cmd + r for refresh.

Answer (score 0):

screenshot does not have any error. You just need to wait until XCode runs the project. Also you should not stop the "terminal" which runs the "bundler". You need a bundler to run the Android/iOS project on React Native.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the app without running through terminal then don't forget to stop remote debugging.

**Stop the remote debugging mode**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. pkill node
2. npm start --reset-cache
3. react-native run-ios

And wait till the iPhone simulator pops up...

Ensure that you are not having a break point in your debugger (e.g. react-native-debugger) which pauses the process of launching the app

Answer (score 0):

1. react-native run-ios
2. Stop Debugging
3. Refresh( cmd + r )